# Uniqueness of factorizing 3D rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, rotations

Consider elementary rotations in 3D of the form (cf. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)),

$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
R_x(\alpha) &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \alpha &  -\sin \alpha \\[3pt]
0 & \sin \alpha  &  \cos \alpha \\[3pt]
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
R_y(\beta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \beta & 0 & \sin \beta \\[3pt]
0 & 1 & 0 \\[3pt]
-\sin \beta & 0 & \cos \beta \\
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
R_z(\gamma) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \gamma &  -\sin \gamma & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \gamma &   \cos \gamma & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{alignat}
$$

Any 3D rotation $U \in SO(3)$ can be written as a product of these matrices,
$$U =\prod_{k=1}^3 R_{i_k}(\theta_k)$$

If we place no further assumption on $U$, is such a factorization unique or can one always find a different order of the matrices with different rotation angles whose product is also $U$?

Comment: As the matrix must be orthogonal, it has only 3 DOFs, so that retrieving the angles amounts to a nonlinear system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns. Given the nonlinearity, one should expect a (small) finite number of distinct solutions.

Comment: "2-axes rotations" => Is this a typo?

Comment: No, what I meant is a rotation in a 2D plane around one fixed axis. I removed the term as it seems to be confusing.

Comment: There are twelve different ordering conventions for [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles), each of which can express any rotation matrix $U$.